# Send Headers in a QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow request

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am using **networkauth** for connecting to an OAuth application. I have been able to successfully authenticate after I receive the **QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::granted** signal.

Had it been a normal QNAM request, it would have been easy. But with networkauth, I don't have access to AccessToken. So I cannot directly send a QNAM request

Now, what is the correct way to send an additional header with my request? Here is my code

```
// private 
// QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow * myObject

connect(this->myObject, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::granted, [=](){
        qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << __LINE__ << "Access Granted!";

        auto m_networkReply = this->myObject->post(QUrl("API_URL"));
// Here I need to post a header in m_networkReply
// setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/json")
// How do I do it?

        connect(m_networkReply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [=](){
            qDebug() << "REQUEST FINISHED. Error? " << (m_networkReply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError);
            qDebug() << m_networkReply->readAll();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AccessToken` can be obtained by `this->myObject->token()` and the header can be set using:

```
m_networkRequest.setRawHeader("Authorization", 
                              "Bearer " + this->myObject->token().toUtf8());
```

So my code snippet becomes:

```
// private 
// QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow * myObject

connect(this->myObject, &QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::granted, [=](){
        qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << __LINE__ << "Access Granted!";

        QJsonObject obj;
        obj.insert("param1", "someval");

        QJsonDocument doc(obj);
        QString strJson(doc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact));

        QNetworkRequest m_networkRequest;
        m_networkRequest.setUrl(QUrl("API_URL"));

        m_networkRequest.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/json");
        m_networkRequest.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + this->myObject->token().toUtf8());

        auto m_networkReply = m_networkAccessManager->post(m_networkRequest, strJson.toUtf8());

        connect(m_networkReply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [=](){
            qDebug() << "REQUEST FINISHED. Error? " << (m_networkReply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError);
            qDebug() << m_networkReply->readAll();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I found for qt6 is to reimplement [QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::prepareRequest](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractoauth2.html#prepareRequest) by this way:

```
void MyFlow::prepareRequest(QNetworkRequest *request, const QByteArray &verb, const QByteArray &body = QByteArray())
{
  QOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow::prepareRequest(request, verb, body);
  
  request->setRawHeader("some header name", "some header data");
}
```

All verb-methods call this function in its implementation.

For older versions of Qt, the only way to add cookies is to call `prepareRequest`:

```
QNetworkReply* FlowWrap::get(const QUrl& url)
{
  QNetworkRequest request(url);
  flow->prepareRequest(&request, QByteArray("GET"));
  request->setRawHeader("some header name", "some header data");
  return flow->networkAccessManager()->get(request);
}
```